# How do you pull child and parent issues using the GitHub API or PyGithub?

Tags: python, github, github-api

In Github, you have the option of referencing issues within an issue. For example, I can make an epic which in turn acts as the parent of n number of child issues I create.

Is there a way to pull linked issues using the [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues) or [PyGithub](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)?

I am able to pull details such as title, state, login_name, issue number, etc. using the API, but cannot figure out how to pull linked issues without writing a complex script that parses through the content of the body.